# On-chain and Off-chain code

Tags: plutus, on-chain

I've seen the existing similar questions on this topic. I probably still don't get it. So a question:
Is it a correct analogy to the JS-Solidity world that

- the On-chain code corresponds to the SmartContract code I write in Solidity (and lives and executes on each node), while,
- the Off-chain code corresponds to the JS client code that shows the UI, prepares and invokes the transaction calls made into the blockchain, and executed by the Smart Contract?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's correct. On-chain is exactly what it says. It's logic that happens on every validator syncing the chain. The unique thing with plutus is the on-chain and off-chain code can live together and share e the same types/imports.